# ios vtb decoder for field interlaced H264

Tags: ios, h.264, decoder

I am having issue( VTDecompressionSesssionDecodeFrame which fails with an error code -12911) decoding interlaced H264 videos. I am passing the SPS, followed by PPS, followed by top field data. The infrastructure I have works for Non-interlaced H264 as well as for interlaced H264 videos with slice structures other than Top/Bottom field. Please let me know in case you need any more info.

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue. Only on iOS, and only with Top/Bottom interlaced fields. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have filed the following bug report with Apple: http://www.openradar.me/30669495

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking out my VTDecompressionSession example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream).  It doesn't handle all different types of H264 (like interlaced H264, I'm not too familiar with that) but perhaps seeing an example may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Livy. In fact I do have an infra with H264 working in general. Its only a particular interlaced contents, which are failing. I did try to use Apple's player based on AVFoundation instead and found it to be not being able to play either. Nonetheless, Thanks for pointing in the right direction.